# Load Image into Application Context Spring from database. I use mybatis api

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, applicationcontext

I use spring-mvc mybatis 3.2.8. I want to read some image from database and store in on ApplicationContext. I have a dao class to read image

**dao class**

```
public Interface DaoImage {
   public List<byte[]> selectImage();
}
```

**InitializationService.java**

```
public interface InitializationiService {
public List<byte[]> loadImage();
}
```

**InitializationServiceImpl.java**

```
public class InitializationImpl implements InitializationService{
@Autowoired
private DaoImage img;

@Overrides 
public List<byte[]> loadImage(){
   return img.selectImage();
}

}
```

**InitializeApplication.java**

```
public class InitializationApplication extends ContextLoaderListener{
@Autowired
private InitializationService service;
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

        List<byte[]> list = service.loadImage();        
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("contextImage", list);


    }

}
```

When the application start the List list = service.loadImage();  is null.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you miss annotation definition in `InitializationServiceImpl.java`.

Try:

```
@Component("initializationService")
public class InitializationImpl implements InitializationService {
...
}
```

In `InitializeApplication.java`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("initializationService")
private InitializationService service;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutioin now :

```
public class InitializationApplication extends ContextLoaderListener implements ServletContextAware{
@Autowired
private InitializationService service;
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext ctx = event.getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ctx);
        InitializationService  service = (InitializationService)springContext.getBean("InitializationService");
        List<byte[]> list = service.loadImage();        
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("contextImage", list);

    }

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
}

}
```